# Vue v-if and remove span

Tags: vue.js

Im using folowing code to render generic table:

```
    <tr v-for="row in filteredData"  >
        <td v-for="column in visibleColumns">
            <span v-if="column.type=='Date'" :class="column.cssClass">{{row[column.field] | formatDate}}</span>
            <span v-else-if="column.type=='Bool'" :class="column.cssClass"><input  @change="genericPost(column.url,row)" class="w3-check" type="checkbox"  v-model="row[column.field]" ></span>
            <span v-else-if="column.type=='Decimal'" :class="column.cssClass">{{row[column.field] | formatPrice}}</span>
            <span v-else-if="column.type=='Button'" :class="column.cssClass"><a  @click="clickItem(column.url,row)" class="w3-button w3-blue w3-padding-small">Edit</a></span>
            <span v-else-if="column.type=='Link'" :class="column.cssClass"><router-link :to="{ path: row.route  }">{{row[column.field]}}</router-link></span>                    
            <span v-else :class="column.cssClass">{{row[column.field]}}</span>
        </td>

    </tr>
```

Is there any way to remove span element from conditional rendering ?
To have simple
`<td class="xxx">value</td>`
 not  `<td><span class="xxx">value</span></td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use v-for with child or sub `<template>` tags.

```
 <tr v-for="row in filteredData" >
     <td v-for="column in visibleColumns" :class="column.cssClass">
        <template v-if="column.type=='Date'">{{row[column.field] | formatDate}}</template>
        <template v-else-if="column.type=='Bool'" ><input  @change="genericPost(column.url,row)" class="w3-check" type="checkbox"  v-model="row[column.field]" ></template>
        <template v-else-if="column.type=='Decimal'" {{row[column.field] | formatPrice}}</template>
        <template v-else-if="column.type=='Button'" ><a  @click="clickItem(column.url,row)" class="w3-button w3-blue w3-padding-small">Edit</a></template>
        <template v-else-if="column.type=='Link'" ><router-link :to="{ path: row.route  }">{{row[column.field]}}</router-link></template>
        <template v-else >{{row[column.field]}}</template>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

In documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt  and https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt

FYI, it appears to be undocumented but it seems you can also use the `<slot>` tag in place of v-for with the `<template>` tags as well. Since I know there are no hidden "gotchas" with the template tag I just use it.